# centos 7 dhclient consumes even 700%+ CPU, miner?

Tags: centos, dhclient

I am new to Linux, I installed CentOS 7.9 in my labtop. I do not know why, sometimes the fan was extremely noisy, then I type `top` to see which one caused this, I found "dhclient" consumes even 700%+ CPU (my CPU has 8 cores?)

```
15967 sshd      30  10 3707632   2.4g   4692 S 784.7 16.0 158:32.13 dhclient                                                                                    
 4134 ring      20   0 4258860 326992 113188 S   9.1  2.0  38:51.93 gnome-shell                                                                                 
 2495 root      20   0  599888 223084  95240 S   1.4  1.4   5:20.28 X                                                                                           
 4780 ring      20   0  681880  41128  19908 S   1.4  0.3   0:31.30 gnome-terminal-                                                                             
11130 root      20   0   39476   1276    988 S   1.4  0.0   8:44.93 monitor                                                                                     
    9 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.3  0.0   0:20.52 rcu_sched                                                                                   
  728 root     -51   0       0      0      0 S   0.3  0.0   0:03.63 irq/141-iwlwifi                                                                             
 4102 ring      20   0   68396   2496   1860 S   0.3  0.0   0:00.47 dbus-daemon                                                                                 
18583 ring      20   0 2828144 168724  62708 S   0.3  1.1   1:52.56 Isolated Web Co                                                                             
18806 ring      20   0 2768992 126664  60628 S   0.3  0.8   1:17.29 Isolated Web Co                                                                             
24739 ring      20   0   58680   2484   1532 R   0.3  0.0   0:00.15 top                                                                                         
    1 root      20   0  194644   7792   4236 S   0.0  0.0   0:07.88 systemd                                                                                     
    2 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.05 kthreadd
```

Then I use `cat /var/log/messages | grep dhclient`, these are messages, could any help find out what happened? what should I do to solve this problem?

```
Jan  1 20:22:51 eda dhclient[15264]: DHCPDISCOVER on virbr0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 15 (xid=0x6ae2ab58)
Jan  1 20:22:54 eda dhclient: [2024-01-01 20:22:54.479]  net      new job from 3389.xiao.my.id:3389 diff 8910K algo rx/0 height 154453
Jan  1 20:23:06 eda dhclient[15264]: DHCPDISCOVER on virbr0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 9 (xid=0x6ae2ab58)
Jan  1 20:23:15 eda dhclient[15264]: DHCPDISCOVER on virbr0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 11 (xid=0x6ae2ab58)
Jan  1 20:23:26 eda dhclient[15264]: DHCPDISCOVER on virbr0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 10 (xid=0x6ae2ab58)
Jan  1 20:23:36 eda dhclient[15264]: DHCPDISCOVER on virbr0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 7 (xid=0x6ae2ab58)
Jan  1 20:23:42 eda dhclient: [2024-01-01 20:23:42.031]  net      new job from 3389.xiao.my.id:3389 diff 9061K algo rx/0 height 154454
Jan  1 20:23:42 eda dhclient: [2024-01-01 20:23:42.956]  miner    speed 10s/60s/15m 1220.6 1257.6 n/a H/s max 2571.8 H/s
Jan  1 20:23:43 eda dhclient[15264]: No DHCPOFFERS received.
Jan  1 20:23:43 eda dhclient[15264]: No working leases in persistent database - sleeping.
Jan  1 20:24:43 eda dhclient: [2024-01-01 20:24:43.326]  miner    speed 10s/60s/15m 1151.4 1164.1 n/a H/s max 2571.8 H/s
Jan  1 20:25:43 eda dhclient: [2024-01-01 20:25:43.586]  miner    speed 10s/60s/15m 1205.5 1283.1 n/a H/s max 2571.8 H/s
Jan  1 20:26:31 eda dhclient[15264]: DHCPDISCOVER on virbr0-nic to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 6 (xid=0x364db7a7)
Jan  1 20:26:37 eda dhclient[15264]: DHCPDISCOVER on virbr0-nic to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 11 (xid=0x364db7a7)
Jan  1 20:26:43 eda dhclient: [2024-01-01 20:26:43.948]  miner    speed 10s/60s/15m 1326.5 1178.2 n/a H/s max 2571.8 H/s
Jan  1 20:26:48 eda dhclient[15264]: DHCPDISCOVER on virbr0-nic to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 9 (xid=0x364db7a7)
Jan  1 20:26:57 eda dhclient[15264]: DHCPDISCOVER on virbr0-nic to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 14 (xid=0x364db7a7)
Jan  1 20:27:11 eda dhclient[15264]: DHCPDISCOVER on virbr0-nic to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 14 (xid=0x364db7a7)
Jan  1 20:27:25 eda dhclient[15264]: DHCPDISCOVER on virbr0-nic to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 7 (xid=0x364db7a7)
Jan  1 20:27:32 eda dhclient[15264]: No DHCPOFFERS received.
Jan  1 20:27:32 eda dhclient[15264]: No working leases in persistent database - sleeping.
Jan  1 20:27:44 eda dhclient: [2024-01-01 20:27:44.309]  miner    speed 10s/60s/15m 1342.5 1264.8 n/a H/s max 2571.8 H/s
Jan  1 20:28:44 eda dhclient: [2024-01-01 20:28:44.574]  miner    speed 10s/60s/15m 1427.7 1411.3 n/a H/s max 2571.8 H/s
Jan  1 20:29:04 eda dhclient: [2024-01-01 20:29:04.105]  net      new job from 3389.xiao.my.id:3389 diff 9216K algo rx/0 height 154455
Jan  1 20:29:32 eda dhclient: [2024-01-01 20:29:32.452]  net      new job from 3389.xiao.my.id:3389 diff 9216K algo rx/0 height 154456
Jan  1 20:29:44 eda dhclient: [2024-01-01 20:29:44.895]  miner    speed 10s/60s/15m 1118.9 1353.9 n/a H/s max 2571.8 H/s
Jan  1 20:30:13 eda dhclient: [2024-01-01 20:30:13.226]  net      new job from 3389.xiao.my.id:3389 diff 9118K algo rx/0 height 154457
Jan  1 20:30:45 eda dhclient: [2024-01-01 20:30:45.234]  miner    speed 10s/60s/15m 1296.6 1291.8 n/a H/s max 2571.8 H/s
Jan  1 20:30:54 eda dhclient[15264]: DHCPDISCOVER on virbr0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 5 (xid=0x611c174c)
Jan  1 20:30:59 eda dhclient[15264]: DHCPDISCOVER on virbr0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 12 (xid=0x611c174c)
Jan  1 20:31:11 eda dhclient[15264]: DHCPDISCOVER on virbr0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 14 (xid=0x611c174c)
Jan  1 20:31:14 eda dhclient[15264]: DHCPDISCOVER on virbr0-nic to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 7 (xid=0x31c502a2)
Jan  1 20:31:21 eda dhclient[15264]: DHCPDISCOVER on virbr0-nic to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 7 (xid=0x31c502a2)
Jan  1 20:31:25 eda dhclient[15264]: DHCPDISCOVER on virbr0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 21 (xid=0x611c174c)
Jan  1 20:31:28 eda dhclient[15264]: DHCPDISCOVER on virbr0-nic to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 15 (xid=0x31c502a2)
Jan  1 20:31:43 eda dhclient[15264]: DHCPDISCOVER on virbr0-nic to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 16 (xid=0x31c502a2)
Jan  1 20:31:45 eda dhclient: [2024-01-01 20:31:45.554]  miner    speed 10s/60s/15m 769.6 1097.3 n/a H/s max 2571.8 H/s
Jan  1 20:31:46 eda dhclient[15264]: DHCPDISCOVER on virbr0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 9 (xid=0x611c174c)
Jan  1 20:31:55 eda dhclient[15264]: No DHCPOFFERS received.
Jan  1 20:31:55 eda dhclient[15264]: No working leases in persistent database - sleeping.
Jan  1 20:31:59 eda dhclient[15264]: DHCPDISCOVER on virbr0-nic to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 8 (xid=0x31c502a2)
Jan  1 20:32:07 eda dhclient[15264]: DHCPDISCOVER on virbr0-nic to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 8 (xid=0x31c502a2)
Jan  1 20:32:15 eda dhclient[15264]: No DHCPOFFERS received.
Jan  1 20:32:15 eda dhclient[15264]: No working leases in persistent database - sleeping.
Jan  1 20:32:45 eda dhclient: [2024-01-01 20:32:45.899]  miner    speed 10s/60s/15m 998.0 1224.7 n/a H/s max 2571.8 H/s
Jan  1 20:33:46 eda dhclient: [2024-01-01 20:33:46.186]  miner    speed 10s/60s/15m 1248.5 1226.1 n/a H/s max 2571.8 H/s
Jan  1 20:34:46 eda dhclient: [2024-01-01 20:34:46.456]  miner    speed 10s/60s/15m 1401.2 1338.0 n/a H/s max 2571.8 H/s
Jan  1 20:35:03 eda dhclient: [2024-01-01 20:35:03.174]  net      new job from 3389.xiao.my.id:3389 diff 9118K algo rx/0 height 154458
```

here is the full messages, ChatGPT say "benchmk" is related to cryptocurrency?!

```
Jan  1 21:02:29 eda dhclient: [2024-01-01 21:02:29.421]  cpu      READY threads 16/16 (16) huge pages 0% 0/16 memory 4096 KB (8 ms)
Jan  1 21:02:38 eda dhclient[15264]: DHCPDISCOVER on virbr0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 11 (xid=0x50f8e063)
Jan  1 21:02:39 eda dhclient: [2024-01-01 21:02:39.419]  benchmk   Algo rx/arq hashrate: 5719.956009
Jan  1 21:02:39 eda dhclient: [2024-01-01 21:02:39.419]  benchmk   Algo panthera Preparation
Jan  1 21:02:39 eda dhclient: [2024-01-01 21:02:39.420]  cpu      stopped (1 ms)
Jan  1 21:02:39 eda dhclient: [2024-01-01 21:02:39.420]  randomx  init dataset algo panthera (8 threads) seed 0000000000000000...
Jan  1 21:02:39 eda dhclient: [2024-01-01 21:02:39.784]  randomx  dataset ready (365 ms)
Jan  1 21:02:39 eda dhclient: [2024-01-01 21:02:39.785]  cpu      use profile  panthera  (4 threads) scratchpad 256 KB
Jan  1 21:02:39 eda dhclient: [2024-01-01 21:02:39.792]  benchmk   Algo panthera Starting test
Jan  1 21:02:39 eda dhclient: [2024-01-01 21:02:39.799]  cpu      READY threads 4/4 (4) huge pages 0% 0/4 memory 1024 KB (15 ms)
Jan  1 21:02:49 eda dhclient[15264]: DHCPDISCOVER on virbr0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 12 (xid=0x50f8e063)
Jan  1 21:02:49 eda dhclient: [2024-01-01 21:02:49.794]  benchmk   Algo panthera hashrate: 1384.323135
Jan  1 21:02:49 eda dhclient: [2024-01-01 21:02:49.794]  benchmk   ALGO PERFORMANCE CALIBRATION COMPLETE
Jan  1 21:02:49 eda dhclient: [2024-01-01 21:02:49.908]  net      3389.xiao.my.id:3389 read error: "end of file"
Jan  1 21:02:57 eda dhclient: [2024-01-01 21:02:57.191]  net      3389.xiao.my.id:3389 read error: "connection reset by peer"
Jan  1 21:03:01 eda dhclient[15264]: DHCPDISCOVER on virbr0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 10 (xid=0x50f8e063)
Jan  1 21:03:04 eda dhclient: [2024-01-01 21:03:04.333]  net      3389.xiao.my.id:3389 read error: "connection reset by peer"
Jan  1 21:03:05 eda dhclient: [2024-01-01 21:03:05.258]  miner    speed 10s/60s/15m n/a n/a n/a H/s max 1474.6 H/s
Jan  1 21:03:11 eda dhclient[15264]: No DHCPOFFERS received.
Jan  1 21:03:11 eda dhclient[15264]: No working leases in persistent database - sleeping.
Jan  1 21:03:29 eda dhclient: [2024-01-01 21:03:29.739]  net      3389.xiao.my.id:3389 34.126.66.198 connect error: "operation canceled"
Jan  1 21:03:34 eda dhclient: [2024-01-01 21:03:34.861]  net      3389.xiao.my.id:3389 read error: "end of file"
Jan  1 21:04:05 eda dhclient: [2024-01-01 21:04:05.419]  miner    speed 10s/60s/15m n/a n/a n/a H/s max 1474.6 H/s
Jan  1 21:05:05 eda dhclient: [2024-01-01 21:05:05.630]  miner    speed 10s/60s/15m n/a n/a n/a H/s max 1474.6 H/s
Jan  1 21:06:05 eda dhclient: [2024-01-01 21:06:05.877]  miner    speed 10s/60s/15m n/a n/a n/a H/s max 1474.6 H/s
Jan  1 21:07:06 eda dhclient: [2024-01-01 21:07:06.089]  miner    speed 10s/60s/15m n/a n/a n/a H/s max 1474.6 H/s
Jan  1 21:07:39 eda kernel: Bluetooth: hci0: Hardware error 0x0c
Jan  1 21:07:39 eda kernel: Bluetooth: hci0: Retrieving Intel exception info failed (-16)
Jan  1 21:08:06 eda dhclient: [2024-01-01 21:08:06.299]  miner    speed 10s/60s/15m n/a n/a n/a H/s max 1474.6 H/s
Jan  1 21:09:06 eda dhclient: [2024-01-01 21:09:06.494]  miner    speed 10s/60s/15m n/a n/a n/a H/s max 1474.6 H/s
Jan  1 21:09:31 eda dhclient[15264]: DHCPDISCOVER on virbr0-nic to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 7 (xid=0xc3a3862)
Jan  1 21:09:38 eda dhclient[15264]: DHCPDISCOVER on virbr0-nic to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 14 (xid=0xc3a3862)
Jan  1 21:09:52 eda dhclient[15264]: DHCPDISCOVER on virbr0-nic to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 12 (xid=0xc3a3862)
```

A new job from here? is this normal?

```
Jan  1 21:32:13 eda dhclient: [2024-01-01 21:32:13.299]  net      new job from 3389.xiao.my.id:3389 diff 8819K algo rx/0 height 154489
```

Comment: [Please don't post images of text](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4086/108618).

Comment: There is indeed the word "miner" in the log.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, this looks like someone managed to run a cryptocurrency miner on your machine under the user name `sshd`. That is not OK.  It's probably just using the process name `dhclient` to not raise alarms as often, because the real `dhclient` is a thing that your computer actually needs to connect to most networks. Someone else has access to your computer, at a level that allows them to interact with the SSH daemon - which would well include things like reading passwords people send.

Long story short: your system has been compromised. Even if you think you managed to clean out anything that resembles the malware, it can't be trusted anymore.

I'm sorry this happened to you, and I have no idea how it happened (unless you installed CentOS from a website that's not CentOS.org or you installed some untrusted software using `sudo` or you used a weak password for a user that has `sudo` privileges and allowed that user to log in via SSH, or something like that).

The honest and way out here is to gather the data you need from your system, and install a freshly downloaded, trustworthy operating system, erasing your current CentOS.